# What is the proper way to access an objects instance-objects instance-variable

Tags: java, object

Let's say i have 2 constructor classes; Person and Arm.

```
public class Person
{
  private Arm arm; //instance variable

  public Person(Arm arm) //Constructor
  {
    this.arm = arm;
  }
}
```

-

```
public class Arm
{
  private int fingers; //instance variable

  public Arm(int fingers) //Constructor
  {
    this.fingers = fingers;
  }

  public int getFingers()
  {
    return this.fingers();
  }

}
```

Every `Person` object has an `Arm` Object as an instance-variable.
Every `Arm` object has an int instance-variable called `fingers`.

What is the proper way to access the `fingers` variable?

1.
Create another getFingers() method, in the Person class:

```
//in Person.java
public int getFingers()
{
  return this.arm.getFingers(); //This is refrencing the getFingers() method in the Arm class
}
```

So i can access it like this:

```
Arm myArm = new Arm(5);
Person me = new Person(myArm);

System.out.println(me.getFingers());
```

2. Create a method in Person that returns the arm.

   ```
   public Arm getArm()
   {
     return this.arm;
   }
   ```

so i can use the getFingers method from the `Arm` class like this:

```
Arm myArm = new Arm(5);
Person me = new Person(myArm);

System.out.println(me.getArm().getFingers())
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile; `Private` and `Public` with a capital 'P' are not proper Java keywords.

Comment: Normally I would say #2, but it really depends on what you are doing, what you are willing to expose publicly, etc..  Also, your call would be `me.getArm().getFingers()`, not `me.myArm.getFingers()`

Comment: @sstan Yes, sorry fixed :)

Comment: @RedRoboHood I'm sorry but i can't find any capital "P"s for any of the access flags in the code?

Comment: @JackPettersson Of course not. You fixed them after I posted my comment.

Comment: @RedRoboHood Ahh, someone else must have, sorry :)

Comment: @JackPettersson Um... no. You did. It's right there in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31271382/revisions).

Comment: @RedRoboHood Apparently i did >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I would suggest that the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) comes into play here.

- Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
- Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
- Only talk to your immediate friends.

If I were to write:

```
A a = new A();
D d = a.getB().getC().getD();
```

then that would allow you to access `D` from an instance of `A` *but* it effectively breaks encapsulation and reveals that an `A` has a `B`, `B` has a `C` etc. etc. You might argue that this is redundant in your case, since you would expect a `Person` to have an `Arm`.

An alternative approach is to think about what you really want the top-level object (`Person`) to do, and *tell it to do it for you*. e.g. if you want the fingers so you can tell them to grasp something (perhaps) then:

```
person.pickUp(object)
```

and the person can determine how to do that itself (it could choose an arm, or it's feet or mouth in extreme situations!). Rather than get the fingers yourself, you're telling the object to do something for you. Which is really what OOP is all about.

Comment: That makes sense, although it will clutter the Person object with a ton of methods (if i were to create more instance-objects and methods for them) hmm... I guess it depends on the remaining code. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I think it depends on that object's responsibilities, and how granular you make those

Answer (score 0):

There is not best practice for this kind of problem.

It is depending on what you like to expose or hide to users of Person class.
If you like to hide the information that Person includes an Arm add a public method `getFingers()` to the class Person. 
If there are not problems exposing the `Arm` class outside then add a method `getArm()` to the class `Person`.

Note that exposing `Arm` if there is a method `setFinger()` in the `Arm` class it is usable from any user of `Person` class.
Exposing a method `getFingers()` block the possibility to directly access the method `setFinger()`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: person.getArmFingers(), useful if you do not want to expose the arm object at all and want all interaction to go through Person object. However keep in mind that every attribute you add to the arm (like hasHair :) will need to be now wrapped through Person which may not be desirable in the long run. If you want to use this consider making the Arm object package private

**Option 2**: Use person.getArm().getFingers(). This will expose the Arm object but will not need every arm attribute to be accessed through Person. This may not be desirable in cases where the Arm in itself has no meaning without being part of a person.

So the answer to your question: It depends

Answer (score 0):

There is really no correct answer as it really depends on usage.

Although, my two cents would be to do both (you already typed them both out anyway!). I would put the functionality in the `Arm` class that way the `Arm` class can be used independently from the `Person` class. Then of course it doesn't hurt to create wrappers in the `Person` class for its members' functionally - especially if you want to keep the members hidden and only allow the `Person` class to be worked with directly. Again, it is dependent on usage.

Just a suggestion. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is famously addressed my [The Law of Demeter (LoD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). This is the *Wikipedia* definition of the *LoD*:

> Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
>   Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
>   Only talk to your immediate friends.

And these are the advantages of following the *LoD*:

> The advantage of following the Law of Demeter is that the resulting software tends to be more maintainable and adaptable. Since objects are less dependent on the internal structure of other objects, object containers can be changed without reworking their callers.

There are also drawbacks that in particular cases might be sufficient to disregard the *LoD*:

> Although the LoD increases the adaptiveness of a software system, it may also result in having to write many wrapper methods to propagate calls to components; in some cases, this can add noticeable time and space overhead.

However, to my knowledge **adhering to the LoD is commonly regarded as good practice**! So, to cut a long story short, go for your *Scenario 1*!